# My proof seems too simple for this abstract algebra problem??

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(X) = a_0 + a_1X + . . . + X^r$ be a monic polynomial with coeﬃcients
$a_i ∈ Z$, and $a_0$ not equal to $0$. Suppose that $f(a) = 0$ for some rational number $a$. Prove that $a$ is an integer which divides $a_0$.

For my answer, i have that since $f(a)=0$, for some rational number $a$, we have:

$a_0+a_1(a)+a_2(a)^2+...+(a)^r=0$

hence $(a_0/a)+a_1+a_2(a)+ ... +a^{r-1}=0$

so $a_0/a = -(a_1+a_2(a)+...+a^{r-1})$

and we have that $a$ divides $a_0$.

However this seems a too simple solution for this 5 mark question. Am i doing something wrong? Have i assumed something that I shouldn't have?

Comment: You haven't proved that $a$ is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

You are close...but not quite there: let us call the root $\;w\;$ for clearity:

$$0=a_0+a_1w+...+w^n\implies a_0=-a_1w-...-w^n\;\;(**)$$

Write now $\;w=\frac pq\;,\;\;p,q\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;(p,q)=1\;$ ,  and multiply (**) by $\;q^n\;$:

$$q^na_0=-q^{n-1}pa_1-\ldots-p^n$$

Observe the above is an **integer** equality, and the right hand side is divisible by $\;p\;$, so *also* the left hand must be divisible by $\;p\;$...but $\;(p,q)=1\;$ , so...

Comment: It's late where I am and I'm probably missing something but why can't $(p|a_0) \wedge (q>1)$ be a possibility? That would still mean $w$ is non-integral. How do you show that $q=1$?

Comment: Who say it can't, @Deepak ? What $\;(p,q)=1\;$ means is that these are coprime integers, and thus $\;p\mid q^na_0\implies p\mid a_0\;$ and you have half your question. Using a similar trick you can now prove that if must be $\;q=\pm 1\;$ and thus $\;w\in\Bbb Z\;$.

Comment: Oh right, of course. Just apply the same trick to $q$ on the LHS and the hanging $p^n$ term on the RHS. Time to sleep now. :)

Comment: Exactly @Deepak...both to your deduction and to your decision to go to sleep. Good night!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: $ $  if $\: r^n\! = a_{n-1}r^{n-1}+\cdots\!+ a_1 r + a_0\ $ for $\ r\in \Bbb Q,\ a_i\in\Bbb Z,\,$ then multiplying by $\,r\,$ shows $\,r^{n+1}$ has the same form, and iterating shows the same for all higher powers of $\,r,\,$ But this implies that a common denominator for $\,r^{n-1},\ldots,r^2,r\,$ is also a common denominator for *all* powers of $\,r.\,$ Therefore  the rational $\,r\,$ must be an integer (*prove* this). *Now* you may conclude as you wrote.